# Pandas: Insert a new Column based on description of previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of around 2800 records. I have a column called as 'Trigger-catogory' which is a Multi-class classification field with one of the attribute being 'CLI-Related'
The dataset has a 'Headline' column and going through the headline i want to further classify it . I have written a code as below

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    rowIndex = df.index[i]
    if df.loc[rowIndex].Trigger_Type == 'CLI-Related':
        cli_related_counter += 1
        headline = df.loc[rowIndex].Headline
        print(headline)
        if re.search('config|push', headline, re.I):
            cc_count+=1  
            df.loc[rowIndex]['Cli-Sub-Cat'] = 'Config'  >>> Trying to insert a new column with a custom value
            continue
        
        if re.search('counter|stat', headline, re.I):
            counter_count+=1
            df.loc[rowIndex]['Cli-Sub-Cat'] = 'Counter'
            continue
            
        if re.search('debug', headline, re.I):
            debug_count+=1
            df.loc[rowIndex]['Cli-Sub-Cat'] = 'debug'
            continue
```

The output that i expect is:

```
    Idenfifier  Headline    Trigger_Type    Cli_Sub_Cat     Prog_Sub_cat
0    1          AAA         CLI-Related       Config        NaN
1    2          BBB         Prog-Related      NaN           Prog-1
2    3          CCC         CLI-Related       Counter       NaN
3    4          DDD         CLI-Related       Config        NaN
4    5          EEE         Prog-Related      NaN           Prog-2
5    6          FFF         Prog-Related      NaN           Prog-3
6    7          GGG         CLI-Related       Debug         NaN
7    8          HHH         Prog-Related      NaN           Prog-1
```

Initially i will be running

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what your question is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use vectorized way via `np.select` to insert a new column:

```
condlist = [
    df.Headline.str.contains('config|push', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True),
    df.Headline.str.contains('counter|stat', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True),
    df.Headline.str.contains('debug', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True),
]
choicelist = [
    'Config',
    'Counter',
    'debug'
]

df['new_column_name_here'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

*NOTE* : you can also add the default value in `np.select`.